# WPF - Binding problem

Tags: wpf, binding

Why after clicking the button the text in the textblock doesn't change ?

XAML:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">Click Me</Button>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
  public partial class Window1 : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Person _myPerson;
    public Person MyPerson
    {
        get { return _myPerson; }
        set
        {
            _myPerson = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyPerson"));
            }
        }
    }

    public Window1()
    {
        MyPerson = new Person { Name = "A" };
        DataContext = MyPerson;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPerson = new Person { Name = "B" };
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

In above code you bind property `Name` with text box and in following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPerson = new Person { Name = "B" };
}
```

You set `MyPerson` to new person.

Is that intended? And does `Person` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` event?

You are only updating `MyPerson` property. `DataContext` still has a reference to the object you create using following line:

```
MyPerson = new Person { Name = "A" };
```

in constructor. You need to update `DataContext` as well.

Instead, use following code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyPerson = new Person { Name = "B" };
    DataContext = MyPerson;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing the datacontext on the click have performance impact? Shouldn't he use the same data context object. Maybe make that as a class member and implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Person class to notify changes on 'Name' member. Then instead of saying MyPerson = new Person { Name = "B" }; if lets say the class member of Person object is mPerson then say, mPerson.Name = "B".

Comment: Well, I did mention that in my answer. But OP did not reply on that. I still recommend implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` in person and changing it's `Name` property instead of creating a whole new `Person` object.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

to

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyPerson, Path=Name}"/>
```

Since you are binding to Name, NotifyPropertyChanged wont be fired on Name when you change MyPerson and the view wont be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement INotifyPropertyChanged on Person class and then just change the name of MyPerson raising PropertyChanged, if you want it to be cleaner...

Or You can re-apply the newly created object you have created to the DataContext, or it won't work